# Python, Pandas, and NLTK Type Error 'int' object is not callable when calling a series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I am trying to get the word frequencies for terms within **each** tweet contained in a dataframe. 
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
import string
import collections
from collections import Counter
nltk.download('stopwords')
sw= set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words ('english'))
punctuation = set (string.punctuation)
data= pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/tweets.csv.zip', compression='zip')

print (data.columns)
print(data.text)
data['text'] = [str.lower () for str in data.text if str.lower () not in sw and str.lower () not in punctuation] 
print(data.text)
data["text"] = data["text"].str.split()
data['text'] = data['text'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in sw])
print(data.text)
data['text'] = data.text.astype(str)
print(type(data.text))
tweets=data.text

data['words']= tweets.apply(nltk.FreqDist(tweets))
print(data.words)
```

And this is my error and traceback:

> Name: text, Length: 14640, dtype: object  Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/leska/.spyder-py3/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/leska/.spyder-py3')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 827, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/leska/.spyder-py3/untitled1.py", line 30, in 
>       data['words']= tweets.apply(nltk.FreqDist(tweets))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 4018, in apply
>       return self.aggregate(func, *args, **kwds)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 3883, in aggregate
>       result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line
>   506, in _aggregate
>       result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line
>   456, in _agg
>       result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line
>   440, in _agg_1dim
>       return colg.aggregate(how, _level=(_level or 0) + 1)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\leska\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 3902, in aggregate
>       result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

I have verified that the type of data.text is a Pandas series.

I had tried a solution earlier that I thought worked that used tokenizing and creating a wordlist to get the word counts, but it resulted in a frequency distribution for ***all*** the tweeets rather than each one. 
This was the code I had tried based on my earlier question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
import string
import collections
from collections import Counter
nltk.download('stopwords')
sw= set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words ('english'))
punctuation = set (string.punctuation)
data= pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/tweets.csv.zip', compression='zip')

print (data.columns)
print (len(data.tweet_id))
tweets = data.text
test = pd.DataFrame(data)
test.column = ["text"]
# Exclude stopwords with Python's list comprehension and pandas.DataFrame.apply.
test['tweet_without_stopwords'] = test['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (sw) and word for word in x.split() if word not in punctuation]))
print(test)
chirps = test.text
splitwords = [ nltk.word_tokenize( str(c) ) for c in chirps ]
allWords = []
for wordList in splitwords:
    allWords += wordList
allWords_clean = [w.lower () for w in allWords if w.lower () not in sw and w.lower () not in punctuation]   
tweets2 = pd.Series(allWords)

words = nltk.FreqDist(tweets2)
```

I really need to the term and counts for ***each*** tweet and I am stumped as to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code snippet, the way you applied the function to the column is the root of the issue.

```py
# this line caused the problem
data['words']= tweets.apply(nltk.FreqDist(tweets))
```

Let's say you get this simple dataframe after cleaning up the tweets and want to apply `nltk.FreqDist` to compute word frequencies in each of the tweets. The function takes any callable.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "tweets": [
            "Hello world",
            "I am the abominable snowman",
            "I did not copy this text",
        ]
    }
)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
|    | tweets                      |
|---:|:----------------------------|
|  0 | Hello world                 |
|  1 | I am the abominable snowman |
|  2 | I did not copy this text    |
```

Now let's find out the word frequencies in each of the three sentences here.

```py
import nltk

# define the fdist function
def find_fdist(sentence):
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentence)
    fdist = FreqDist(tokens)

    return dict(fdist)

# apply the function on `tweets` column
df["words"] = df["tweets"].apply(find_fdist)
```

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
|    | tweets                      | words                                                         |
|---:|:----------------------------|:--------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0 | Hello world                 | {'Hello': 1, 'world': 1}                                      |
|  1 | I am the abominable snowman | {'I': 1, 'am': 1, 'the': 1, 'abominable': 1, 'snowman': 1}    |
|  2 | I did not copy this text    | {'I': 1, 'did': 1, 'not': 1, 'copy': 1, 'this': 1, 'text': 1} |
```

Comment: Inspect what your `data["text"]` column looks like. If it has valid sentences in each row, this shouldn't happen. In that case, maybe you can share the dataset with me and I can attempt to reproduce the issue.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I would like to clean the result better, but this is what I needed and I think I even understand it. Many thanks!

Comment: And the error I was getting was because I forgot the return statement.....supremely stupid mistake!